# using session variables on home page to show account links

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I need some links (related to user account) to appear on the index page for the user who logged in. i have a session variable'email'.
i did this but it didn't work.

```
<div id="left">
    left div content
    </div>

    <div id=-"right">

    <?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {

    ?>
    //show user some links to his account.
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    //show login and register forms
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you add session_start(); at the top of your page?

Comment: Have you called `session_start();` at top of script?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you describe what you want to achieve better? Also, `id=-` is not proper Id for DOMElement.

Comment: is it necessary to add session_start(); to every page where i use session variables? (just started learning php.)

Comment: Yes it is necessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    session_start(); // add this line
    if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {

    ?>
```

[Link](https://www.php.net/session_start) to php manual.

Comment: i'm using localhost. whenever i open index.php in new tab after login it shows login and register forms. But on the same it works. how?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

your first statement within the

```
<?php 

   session_start();

  //followed by rest of the code.

?>
```

should be

`session_start();`

Then the further code.